# How to optimize Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make an animation on a div child element when i hover the child of a different div this is my code:

```js
$('.section li:nth-child(1)').hover(function(){
    $('.section2 li:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('is-over');
});
  
$('.section li:nth-child(2)').hover(function(){
    $('.section2 li:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('is-over');
});

$('.section li:nth-child(3)').hover(function(){
    $('.section2 li:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('is-over');
});

$('.section li:nth-child(4)').hover(function(){
    $('.section2 li:nth-child(4)').toggleClass('is-over');
});
```

So how can i optimize it?

Comment: CodeReview is probably a better network for such kind of questions. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Optimise for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).index()` to get the index of `hovered` item

```js
$('.section li').hover(function(){
  var index = $(this).index()+1;
  $('.section2 li:nth-child('+index+')').toggleClass('is-over');
});
```

```css
.is-over {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="section">
    <li>Step 1</li>
    <li>Step 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="section2">
    <li>Step 11</li>
    <li>Step 22</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is broad question.

You can create a function like this

```
function hoverChild(child){
  $('.section li:nth-child('+child+')').hover(function(){
            $('.section2 li:nth-child('+child+')').toggleClass('is-over');
        });
}
```

and on requirement call this function as

```
hoverChild(n) where n =1,2,3....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.section li').hover(function(){
    var num = $(this).index();
    $('.section2 li:nth-child('+num+')').toggleClass('is-over');
});
```